# "Draw blood on Day 1, 5 and 6" or "Draw blood on Days 1, 5 and 6"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Should I use plural or singular noun in a sentence like this:

"The researchers will draw your blood on Day 1, 5 and 6." vs "…Days 1, 5 and 6."?

I think the first sentence is correct, but I am not sure why. I would like to hear your thoughts, too. Thanks.

Comment: Days 1, 5 and 6 would also be correct. The choice is a matter of style I think.

Comment: Thanks for your comment